# Can't build Make3.82 on Ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: android, gcc, make

I use an Ubuntu server to build Android.  I upgraded to 16.04.1 which has make 4.1.  Android requires Make 3.82 to build.

I downloaded make 3.82 from https://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/make/.  When I run `./configure` in the `make3.82` dir, I get the error:

```
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

The config.log has a more specific error:

```
gcc: error trying to exec 'cc1': execvp: No such file or directory
```

I've tried reinstalling `gcc`, resetting up the entire android build environment but I still get this error.  Everything seems to point to cc1 not being installed which seems like the problem because I don't even have a `/usr/libexec/` directory.  I thought this directory got installed whenever gcc did.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `make` depends on various other tools which will only be compatible within a certain range of versions. You will need to install the whole tool-chain to have a chance to make it work.

Comment: @MadMike Is there an ubuntu command to install the whole tool chain for make 3.82?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the subject.. but for what it's worth this is what google told me: http://askubuntu.com/q/509012/75166

Comment: This post is not about the same problem.  That person already has both versions of make installed.  He is not failing to install make.